# How to get number of resources in directory in spring?

Tags: java, spring

```
@Value("file:" + "${d:/my/dir/}")
private Resource dir;
```

How can I get the number of files in that resource dir? Unfortunately the `Resource` interfaces does not offer any getFiles() method...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java resource as file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676097/java-resource-as-file)

search through the site a bit before posting, the answer is likely already there. specifically [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1089408/1197030)

Comment: I know there are possibilities with native java file package. But I explicit requested the use of spring `Resource`, maybe there is also a chance of directly getting the dir content through the spring.

Comment: my appologies, I had missed the spring Resource part, but if it is a directory the Resource points to then you can simply use getFile() on it to get a File ref. and on File you can call isDirectory and list(). At least based on the Resource interface, this seems to be the case

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this version](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) of the Resource interface, you can call getFile

```
File theDir = dir.getFile();
if (theDir.isDirectory()) {
    theDir.list();
}
```

if you combine this with the [propertyplaceholderconfigurer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/760706/1197030) you might get what you're lookign for: